# When using the target option in terraform, why does it sometimes return other resources alongside the one targeted?

Tags: terraform

I was creating a cloudwatch alarm in my ELB stack like so:

```
module "elb_sg" {
  source                   = "git@github.com:terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-security-group.git"
  name                     = "${local.name}-elb-sg"
  description              = "Allow internet inbound traffic"
  vpc_id                   = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_id}"
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = "${data.null_data_source.elb_sg_rules.*.inputs}"
  tags                     = "${local.tags}"

  # Open egress for all
  egress_with_cidr_blocks = "${local.open_egress}"
}

#  ELB
module "elb" {
  source                      = "git@github.com:terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-elb.git"
  name                        = "${local.name}"
  subnets                     = ["${split(",",local.elb_subnets)}"]
  internal                    = "${var.internal}"
  security_groups             = "${local.elb_security_group_ids}"
  cross_zone_load_balancing   = "${var.cross_zone_load_balancing}"
  idle_timeout                = "${var.idle_timeout}"
  connection_draining         = "${var.connection_draining}"
  connection_draining_timeout = "${var.connection_draining_timeout}"
  listener                    = ["${var.listener}"]
  access_logs                 = ["${var.access_logs}"]
  health_check                = ["${var.health_check}"]
  tags                        = "${local.tags}"
}


# Cloudwatch alarms
data "aws_elb" "classic_lb" {
  count = "${module.elb.this_elb_name != "" ? 1 : 0}"
  name  = "${module.elb.this_elb_name}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "low_healthy_host_count_alarm" {
    count                = "${var.create_alarm ? 1 : 0}"
    # alarm_name         = "${module.elb.this_elb_name}-HealthyHostCount"
    alarm_name           = "${data.aws_elb.classic_lb.name}-HealthyHostCount"
    dimensions {
      # LoadBalancerName = "${module.elb.this_elb_name}"
      LoadBalancerName   = "${data.aws_elb.classic_lb.name}"
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I tried to use `data source` as well as direct module access like `${module.elb.this_elb_name}` for getting the ELB name as it exists on AWS (and not on my local as sometimes AWS can truncate long names). But both times when targeting just the alarm like `terraform plan -target=aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.low_healthy_host_count_alarm`, I get other resources targeted too, which I don't want.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.low_healthy_host_count_alarm
      id:                                    <computed>
      actions_enabled:                       "true"
      ...

  ~ module.elb_sg.aws_security_group.this
      ...

  ~ module.elb.module.elb.aws_elb.this
      access_logs.#:                         "0" => "1"
      access_logs.0.bucket:                  "" => "test-logs"
      access_logs.0.enabled:                 "" => "true"
      access_logs.0.interval:                "" => "60"
      ...


Plan: 1 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

The problem goes away when I use a hardcoded name or a `local.name` for the elb in dimension and alarm_name in my cloudwatch alarm.

Can someone explain exactly what causes this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the full config, the easiest assumption is they are dependencies of the resource.

Comment: thanks @MattSchuchard just added all the relevant config.

Answer (score 0):

As per this official [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting), when we specify a module path, the "target" applies to all resources in the specified module and all of the descendent modules of the specified module.

This is why when use a hardcoded value for the elb, we dont get dependencies be targeted.

But we are using the [module path](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/resource-addressing.html), docs for which also mention, " If a module path is specified without a resource spec, the address applies to every resource within the module. "